# extend faceted search by adding category filter in alfresco 5.1

Tags: alfresco-share

How to extend faceted search by adding category filter in alfresco 5.1.by default in faceted search CreatedBy,Modified By,FileSize etc filters are there.If we want to add Category filter then how to extend the code?

Comment: Have you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search manager feature allows a member of the "Search Administrators" group to configure the facets that used in search. It is possible to select any property in the data model to be faceted on - but Category is not a model property. It is possible to create custom queries that Solr can execute and Alfresco provides a couple out-of-the-box for "Tag" and "Site". Unfortunately I don't know the details of how these were implemented, but you should in theory be able to implement a similar custom query for "Category".